# Minimum sample size for estimating unique followers of three Instagram accounts

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, survey-sampling

I want to determine the number of unique followers between three (or more) large (>1e6 followers) Instagram accounts. Is there a way to determine the minimum number of followers per account I would need to estimate the unique followers count given some desired level of confidence?

I've been reading about the central limit theorem, confidence intervals, and survey sample size calculators, but I feel like my problem is more complicated because the populations overlap and I'm sorta studying the extent to which they overlap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the number of followers common to all three (or more) accounts? or are you trying to do pair-wise comparisons between accounts? How precise does your estimate need to be?

Comment: Also, what is preventing you from just comparing all followers as opposed to a sample?

Comment: Hi CFD, ultimately I'm interested in the number of unique followers which I guess will equal the sum of the number of followers in common to all three, in common to only two, and in common to only one. In terms of precision, I'm open to any level but to within 5% would be dope. The lack of a public Instagram API and the slowness of unofficial APIs prevent me from obtaining lists of all followers to compare them directly.